# Passing a struct with a void function

Tags: c++, struct

I have the struct of:

```
const int strSize = 256;
const int databaseMaxSize = 10;

struct ComicInfo {
char name[strSize];
char author[strSize];
char volumeInfo[strSize];
char publisher[strSize];
int year;
double price;
int copies;
};
```

How would I pass the struct and the databaseMaxSize to a void function and is that all I have to do to the struct?

Edit: Full code, I know I didn't call the void function.
I am trying to get the 7 variables into the void loadData function, How would I create a correct loadData function and am I correctly loading in the data from the text file "Comics.txt"?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

const int strSize = 256;
const int databaseMaxSize = 10; // Testing value, set it higher

struct ComicInfo {
char name[strSize];
char author[strSize];
char volumeInfo[strSize];
char publisher[strSize];
int year;
double price;
int copies;
};

void loadData(struct ComicInfo database[databaseMaxSize], int databaseSize);

int main () {
        ComicInfo database[databaseMaxSize];
        int databaseSize = 0;

        file.close();

        return 0;
}

void loadData(struct ComicInfo database[databaseMaxSize], int databaseSize)
{
        *databaseSize = 0;

        ifstream inputFile;
        inputFile.open("Comics.txt");

        if (!inputFile.is_open){
                exit(1);
        }

        inputFile.getline(database[name], databaseSize, ',');
        while (!inputFile.eof()){
                inputFile.getline(database[author], databaseSize, ',');
                inputFile.getline(database[volumeInfo], databaseSize, ',');
                inputFile.getline(database[publisher], databaseSize, ',');
                inputFile.getline(database[year], databaseSize, ',');
                inputFile.getline(database[price], databaseSize, ',');
                inputFile.getline(database[copies], databaseSize, ',');
                databaseSize++;
                inputFile.getline(database[name], databaseSize, ',');
                }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain a lit more about the function and task you are trying to accomplish , what's your void function , is that taking void params and returning void or something else.

Comment: It's not clear what "void function" is what your problem exactly is. Would you mind providing some example code showing what are you trying to achieve, what have you tried, and what was the outcome.

Comment: I am trying to pass the 7 "variables" into a void function, then opening a file and reading the data into the variables. I have this line of code in my main function, not knowing wether or not it should be there: "ComicInfo database[databaseMaxSize];"

Comment: The void function that I have tried and the errors were that the variables were not declared in that scope: "void loadData(struct ComicInfo database[databaseMaxSize], int databaseSize);"

Comment: Please write the complete code that you have written with errors that you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

```
void my_function (struct ComicInfo& st, int databaseMaxSize) {
// code
}
```

Note that we are passing a reference to the object so that extra copies of the object are not created. If the `my_function` is not supposed to make changes in the  struct data, the argument can be marked as `const struct ComicInfo&`

Invocation:

```
struct ComicInfo a;
my_function(a, databaseMaxSize); // Assuming you have databaseMaxSize available
```

Comment: I am confused about the "a" in the invocation, what does it mean?

Comment: @JonathanL, that `a` is the name of the object of type `struct ComicInfo`. The object name can be any name you like.